# iPhone In App Email Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

when I press the sendMail button, it will go to the mail button, but when I hit send or cancel it will not take me back to my application.  Any suggestions?

```
-(IBAction)sendMail {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease] ;

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:nil];
        [mailComposer setSubject:nil];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Default text" isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line below your mail composer initialization

```
 mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;//very important if you want feedbacks on what the user did with your email sheet.
```

Then implement the delegate method as Kenny suggested. You can use this method to take custom actions.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{ 
 // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
 switch (result)
 {
 case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
     {
      //Do something, If you need to
     }
 break;

 default:
 break;
 }
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Remember to conform to the delegate  by adding

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> { }
```

If you are still having trouble, You may visit the following tutorial where everything nicely explained:
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a delegate (generally the same view controller that presented the MFMailComposeViewController). Then when the user taps the Save or Cancel button the MFMailComposeViewController will call -mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error on the delegate. So set yourself as the delegate and define the following method:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MessageUI Delegate Methods

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error {

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I plugged in this code but the same problem, what do you mean by set yourself as the delegate.

Comment: When you init the compose controller you need to set composeController.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

This wonderful line:

```
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

is what made ​​it happen for days without knowing that was what went wrong.

And do not forget them:

```
# import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
# import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
# import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

In addition to importing the `MessageUI.framework` in the project.

Verified in IOS5